# Display page content using getResources - ModX

Tags: modx

I'm trying to create FAQ page in ModX using `getResources`.
In CMS user need to create new page and move it to the right place, so *FAQ* page will be parent for it. I dont know how to display page content.

[getResources documentation](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResources.Category+Index+Page+with+Thumbnails)

Here is FAQ page content:

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`25` &showHidden=`1` &limit=`100` &tpl=`FAQs` &sortby=`menuindex` &sortdir=`ASC`]]
```

Here is *FAQs* chunk code:

```
<div class="faq">
<h5>[[+pagetitle]]</h5>
[[+content]]
</div>
```

By this code i can see only page's titles in *h5* tags as a list, without content under each question. How to display content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you are missing is the &includeContent=`1` parameter...  it is in your example page, but the actual docs are here: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResources Also if you are still having trouble, omit the &tpl parameter and getResources will basically dump its results straight to the page, pretty useful to see what you are actually getting back.